# SwiftMailer - Yii2 can't send email

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

I have problem using swiftmailer with yii2.

```
'components' => [
        'mailer' => [
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport'        => [
                'class'    => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host'     => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
                'port'     => 587,
                'username' => 'noreply@mysociete.com',
                'password' => 'MY API KEY HERE',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

to send after user registration i use the code below :

```
    $isSuccessfullySaved = $leadModel->save();

    if (!$isSuccessfullySaved) {
        $response = $this->asJson(['errors' => ['webservice' => 'Error while saving the lead']]);
        $response->statusCode = 550;
        return $response->send();
    }

    $lastStep = Json::decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../config-offers/offers.json'));
    
    $isSuccessfullySent = Yii::$app->mailer->compose(
        'offer-summary',
        ArrayHelper::merge($leadModel->getAttributes(), $lastStep['offres'][$bestOffer])
    )
 
        ->setFrom(['noreply@mysociete.com' => 'My Societe'])
        ->setTo($leadModel->emailAddress)
        ->setSubject('mysociete.com- Votre offre')
        ->send();

    if (!$isSuccessfullySent) {
        Yii::error("Could not send the email", __METHOD__);
    }
```

What should be wrong. There is no error written in any log.

Comment: check what is returned by `->send();`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the encryption in the transport? I am not sure about Mandrillapp needing it, but you could give it a try:

```
'transport'        => [
  'class'    => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
  'host'     => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  'port'     => 587,
  'username' => 'noreply@mysociete.com',
  'password' => 'MY API KEY HERE',
  'encryption' => 'tls',
],
```